# Prevent $anchorScroll from modifying the url

Tags: angularjs, url

I am using [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) to scroll to page top where the html element has ID `#brand`.

```
<body>
    <header id="brand">
        <!--Content-->
    </header>
</body>
```

AngularJS code:

```
$location.hash("brand");
$anchorScroll();
```

However, after `$anchorScroll` runs, the page url becomes `http://localhost:8080/##brand`, which means `##brand` is appended to the original url. How can I keep the original url when using `$anchorScroll`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using $anchorScroll in its explicit form seems to work, at least when [html5mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) is on.

```
(do not call $location.hash())
$anchorScroll('brand');
```

Comment: Thanks! Saved me time.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to prevent the hash from being added to the URL; you are explicitly doing just that by invoking `$location.hash("brand");`. You can, however, remove it by invoking `$location.hash(null);` after anchorScroll.

Comment: its also working but we don't need to add two extra line