# How to hide the $anchorScroll in the browser in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am fairly new to AngularJS and I am using `$anchorScroll` to scroll to a particular section of the page after the results are rendered (which works fine).

However, I would like to hide the anchor that appears in the browser (refer to the image below). How can I achieve that?

[image]

Here's the section in the controller where I am using `$anchorScroll` and where I display the results after the user hits submits. Any help would appreciated:

```
$scope.SearchProvider = function(searchParam) {
    try{
        $scope.searchMode = 1;
        var queryString='';
        if($scope.formModel && $scope.formModel !== searchParam){
            $scope.resultsCount = 0;
            currentPage = 1;
        }
        if(searchParam){
            $scope.formModel = searchParam;
            for(var param in searchParam){
                if(searchParam.hasOwnProperty(param)){
                    var paramValue = searchParam[param].value ? searchParam[param].value.trim() : searchParam[param].trim();
                    if (paramValue.length > 0)
                        queryString += param + '=' + paramValue + '&';
                }
            }
        }
        //debugger;
        console.log(queryString);
        queryString= '?' + queryString + 'currentpage=' + $scope.currentPage;

        $http.get("/includes/ReturnProvidersList.cfm" + queryString)
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.providers = response.data.provider;
            $scope.resultsCount = response.data.rowCount;
            if (!$scope.providers){
                    $scope.NoResults = true;
                    $scope.ShowResults = false;
                    $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                    $location.hash('error');

                    // call $anchorScroll()
                    $anchorScroll('error');
                }
            else {
                    $scope.NoResults = false;
                    $scope.ShowResults = true;
                    $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                    $location.hash('ResultsAnchor');

                    // call $anchorScroll()
                    $anchorScroll('ResultsAnchor');
                }
        })
    }
    catch(err){ alert('No response.: ' + err.message); }
}
```

Comment: It is already addressed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079284/prevent-anchorscroll-from-modifying-the-url

Comment: @Chinni: Thank You. it appears there isn't a way to do it for older version of IE. Thank you

Comment: Didn't that answer I've referred to not work?

Comment: @Chinni it does not work for older version of IE and does not work for Chrome or Firefox. Instead, it affects my drop down boxes values to not appear.

Comment: @Chinni I did a little more research and I found I can do **document.getElementById('ResultsAnchor').scrollIntoView(true);**.Although it does work, I do have a question: Can I applied this to my controller? Sorry if the question is stupid. I am not sure

Comment: As far as I know you can use it. May be you can try to accomplish it using `angular.element`.

Comment: @Chinni: Thank You. The reason I ask is that I am trying to figure out how to grab **"$scope.showResults = true"** value which can be true or false and from there use the "scrollIntoView()" approach

Comment: You can take $anchorScroll source code and suit it to your needs in custom service. If you have specific problems with implementation, consider addressing them specifically.